# Extracting Joint angles of FBX file

Tags: python, .fbx, motion-capture, quaternion

I recorded some motion capture data with a markerless tracking system. All the data needed for the animation is stored in a .fbx file. Overall I am interested in joint angles. The ankle joint angles should be given in euler angles and the hip joint angles should be stored in quaternions.

Is there a way to extract these? My blender experience is rather small but I can code using Python or MATLAB. Would it be easiest to write a script? ANd if so how would I get to thiss stores angle data?

Thanks for any suggestions!